# Building docker images in kuberentes cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-image

We have a requirement to build custom docker images from base docker images with some additional packages/customization. These custom docker images need to be then deployment into kubernetes. We are exploring various tools to figure out on how docker build can be done in kubernetes cluster (without direct access to docker daemon). Open source tools like kaniko provides the capability to build docker images within a container (hence in a kubernetes cluster).

1. Is it a good practice is build docker images in kubernetes cluster where other containers will be run/executed? Are there any obvious challenges with kaniko?
2. Should separate dedicated VMs be created to manage the build process?

Comment: FYI, the builder tools list: https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/issues/596

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Is it a good practice is build docker images in kubernetes cluster where other containers will be run/executed?
Are there any obvious challenges with kaniko?**

Yes, it is possible to build images inside [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io) containers, but it could be a bit of a challenge.

Some users use it to build a workflow for [CI/CD with Jenkins](https://kublr.com/blog/using-jenkins-and-kubernetes-for-continuous-integration-and-delivery/). In fact, it is better to use tools to simplify the process.

Kubernetes also have rules to prepare containers development kit, they are described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/)

Another way is to use [Kaniko](https://kublr.com/blog/using-jenkins-and-kubernetes-for-continuous-integration-and-delivery/), this tool builds container images from a Dockerfile inside a container or Kubernetes cluster.

I found this article interesting to read on this [topic](https://applatix.com/case-docker-docker-kubernetes-part-2/).

On the other hand, there was a successful attempt to build images without Docker daemon running. You may be interested in [Bazel](https://bazel.build/) project and [story](https://medium.com/bitnami-perspectives/building-docker-images-without-docker-c619061b13a9) how to use it.

**2. Should separate dedicated VMs be created to manage the build process?**

Regarding your second question: It is not necessary to set up dedicated VM to run Docker images creation workflow.

Finally, it may be interesting to have a [private registry](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/registry) in Kubernetes cluster and use it for building purposes.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to build images on kubernetes nodes. But i wouldn't recommend it. The reason being, a application build process is memory and compute intensive, frequent image builds could cause disruption to services being scheduled by that kubernetes node.

Use a dedicated Jenkins server(s) instead, create pipelines according to your requirements and delivery.

You can get started [here](https://kublr.com/blog/using-jenkins-and-kubernetes-for-continuous-integration-and-delivery/)!

Hope that helps!